# How to ignore data previously counted by countif and return a specific value in cell

Tags: excel, countif

I am attempting to exclude values my countif formula has already counted, and instead insert a value such as "Already counted".

I need to count how many times a specific item appears in a column, which I used the basic countif formula for:  =COUNTIF(A:A,A2).  It returned these results:

Name        # of Name

Mike        2

Sally       2

John        3

Kim     2

Jose    2

Sally   2

John    3

Brenda  1

John    3

Jose    2

Kim     2

Mike    2

(Column A is the "Name", Column B is the formula column "# of Name".)

OK, great.  The issue is when the second occurrence of "Sally" happens, it counts the word again.  I would like to ignore it because it has already been counted, and instead insert another value, such as "Already Counted".  Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MATCH to test if first in the list:

```
=IF(MATCH(A2,A:A,0)=ROW(),COUNTIF(A:A,A2),"Already Counted")
```

[image]

Comment: This worked great.  Now I have to figure it out so I can teach it to others.

Comment: Since Match returns the relative position of the first match it returns the row number of the first time the word is used.  We are just testing whether what match returns is equal to the row in which the formula is located.  If it is it is the first time.

Comment: @Justin now you need to accept one as the correct answer.  Choose the one you used by clicking the check mark by the answer.  Unfortunately you can only choose one as both will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can `COUNTIF` for the limited range ending with the current row, and, if more than `1`, you know it was already counted

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)=1,COUNTIF($A:$A,A2),"Already Counted")
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Having just seen it, I like Scott's solution also.

Comment: Both work and neither is advantageous over the other.

Comment: Probably a silly question, but would this make it difficult to tell which items occurred only once?

Comment: @Justin You could use conditional formatting to highlight those rows where the count equals 1