# How to ignore values already counted in previous rows for cumulative count

Tags: excel, match, countif, cumulative-sum

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
Sample  Species1    Species2    Species3    Cumulative count
1       1                                   1
2       1           1                       2
3       1                                   2
4       2                                   2
5       1           2           1           3
```

I would like to count every new species added by each sample. So in the example above, samples 3 and 4 don't add any new species to the total number of species, so their cumulative count remains the same (I am trying to create a species accumulation curve).

I have tried this, but cannot get it to work with numbers >0 (for instance), rather than text:
[How to ignore data previously counted by countif and return a specific value in cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46160451/how-to-ignore-data-previously-counted-by-countif-and-return-a-specific-value-in)

Essentially, I need something to check if the species in the current row were already present in previous rows.
The goal is to produce a graph like this, so I can determine where sampling effort begins to have a diminishing return (in number of species):
[image]

Is there an excel formula I could use to fill the 'Cumulative count' column and return the results above? I should also mention that a short solution would be best, because I have 35+ species and the formulas can get long and complicated very quickly. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, the maximum sum is 3 in the above example. I want to plot the number of samples against the cumulative sum to determine where the best trade-off between effort and return is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going horizontal is easy smaller formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B3:D3>0)*1,(B$2:D2<=0)*1)+E2
```

.......

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B6:D6>0)*1,(B$2:D2<=0)*1,(B$3:D3<=0)*1,(B$4:D4<=0)*1,(B$5:D5<=0)*1)+E5
```

[image]

[image]

I found a method but this probably can be refined a bit:

For our first Cum Count Row:

```
=COUNTIF(B2:D2,"<>" & "")
```

For each thereafter:

```
=IF(AND(B3>0,SUM(B$2:B2)<=0),1,0)+IF(AND(C3>0,SUM(C$2:C2)<=0),1,0)+IF(AND(D3>0,SUM(D$2:D2)<=0),1,0)+E2
```

.....................

```
=IF(AND(B6>0,SUM(B$2:B5)<=0),1,0)+IF(AND(C6>0,SUM(C$2:C5)<=0),1,0)+IF(AND(D6>0,SUM(D$2:D5)<=0),1,0)+E5
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks - that is a solution. However, I have 35+ species, which would take a while to create equations for. A shorter solution would be better. I've been trying SUMPRODUCT but I can't get it to work.

Comment: @Grubbmeister new edit cuts formula by 25%. UDF may work best. To be fair in your question you mention "is there an excel formula."

Answer (score 0):

A shorter solution is a UDF, and is provided here by [JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv):
stackoverflow.com/questions/51980149/count-column-if-it-contains-a-filled-cell-in-excel/51980258

> Well, I guess if you want to work without any helper rows to use the
>   COUNTA funtion a smooth way could be a UDF, possibly like so:
>
> ```
> Function CountColumns(RNG As Range) As Long
>
> Dim COL As Range
> For Each COL In RNG.Columns
>     If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(COL) > 0 Then CountColumns = CountColumns + 1
> Next COL
>
> End Function
> ```